# Grub Problem, Boot-Repair not working

Tags: boot, grub2, wubi

I am using a Wubi installation installed through Windows 7. I have lots of problem with grub and nothing is working. I have important files in the partition. I can boot through a live CD if necessary.

Here's the pastebin link to boot-repair.

- http://paste.ubuntu.com/1109188

Comment: looking at your pastebin, you installed Ubuntu via Wubi, I'm not sure but I don't think Boot Repair will work with Wubi.  If you installed with Wubi, you need to edit your question to reflect that and add `Wubi` tag to your question.

Answer (score 0):

1. run a live-cd, precise pangolin is probably the best option
2. mount the partition where Ubuntu is and take note of the mount point
3. run this `sudo grub-install --root-directory=/mount/point /dev/sdX`

where sdX is the label for the HDD where Grub will boot from.

You should be fine, just reboot the PC, eventually, after booting Ubuntu from your HDD, just run `sudo update-grub`.